# Account linking with different emails

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth on iOS (Swift). In my app, there are only 2 ways for users to create an account:

1. Email (email/password)
2. Sign In with Apple

Here's an example that I'm not sure what to do in regards to account linking:

1. A user creates an account with option #1 (Email) and signs up with `jake@gmail.com`
2. The user logs out of the account and closes app
3. The user opens app, and instead of using option #1 (Email) to sign in to the already created account, he tries to login with option #2 (Sign In with Apple). However, his Apple ID email is `jakeApple@gmail.com` and is not the same as `jake@gmail.com`

*Note: This all happens on the same phone*

This creates 2 accounts in Firebase because the emails are different. I have 1 account per email enabled in Firebase dashboard by default and want to keep this option since it is recommended. Is there anyway to link these 2 accounts together? Also, should they be linked together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really know they are the same users if their emails differ (anyone can create an email that is similar to another email). So you shouldn't want to build functionality that automatically links the 2 users.

That said, you can manually use the `linkWithCredential` API to link the Apple credential to the email/password user provided that user is already signed in, but I think you shouldn't require this unless the email/password user wants to do so (via some button to link their Apple account).

Comment: Thanks, I will take your advice and not link the two automatically. I also won't even present this as an option. Thanks for response!!

Comment: I have a similar question that should be really quick to answer. Hopefully you can take look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61072485/apple-replaces-email-provider-if-email-not-verified