# Apple replaces email provider if email not verified

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have read about this issue in multiple places such as [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1180#issuecomment-370546878) but do not know what user experience to give users.

I'm using Firebase Auth on iOS (Swift). In my app, there are only 2 ways for users to create an account:

1. Email (email/password)
2. Sign In with Apple

I'm not sure how to handle this scenario where Apple replaces the email provider in Firebase:

1. User signs up with option #1 (Email) as `john@gmail.com`. We use the api [send email verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email) to send an email for user to verify their email.
2. This user does not open email to verify their email for some reason. Therefore, the email is not verified.
3. User logs out of the app.
4. Instead of the user logging in with option #1 (Email), the user logs in with option #2 (Sign In with Apple). Their Apple ID email is the same as option #1 (Email): `john@gmail.com`.  We use the API [sign in with credential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#signinwith:completion:).

In this flow, **Apple replaces the email provider** because both their regular email and Apple ID email are the same (and the regular email was not verified). If the email is verified, Firebase links the email and Apple account automatically in this case... instead of replacing.

If you try to create an account with option #1 (Email) again later you'll get this error because it is already used with Apple:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17007 "The email address is already in use by another account." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The email address is already in use by another account., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE}
```

I'm not sure what to do here for user experience if the user wants to login with email but now can't. Do I tell the user: "Sorry, since you did not verify your email, Apple replaced the email provider as an option and now you have to use Apple to login to your account"? Or is there a better user experience we could provide to user? Is there anyway to easily allow this user to use both email and Apple as a way to login in this specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you call `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` to get the IdPs associated with this email. That will return a list with `apple.com` provider ID. You inform the user that they need to sign in with Apple to that account.

Going forward they would need to use Apple sign-in. The only way to use both is if you verify the email (via email verification) after they sign up with email/password and before they sign in with Apple. When the account is verified, the Apple credential is merged automatically on sign-in and the password is kept on the account.

Comment: Thanks for response! Quick followup: when you say: " You inform the user that they need to sign in with Apple to that account." --> does this mean the user has to use Apple sign in going forward? Basically, I will inform the user that from now on, only Apple sign in will work and regular email/password will not? This is my main concern - if there was a way to still let them continue to use both options even though Apple replaced email as the provider.

Comment: Going forward they would need to use Apple sign-in. The only way to use both is if you verify the email (via email verification) after they sign up with email/password and before they sign in with Apple. When the account is verified, the Apple credential is merged automatically on sign-in and the password is kept on the account. Will add to answer.

Comment: Thank you, it's great to get clarification on this! I truly appreciate you taking the time to answer this, so helpful!!

Comment: Good explanations thank you - just one thing:  My Email/Password from Firebase is verified but it still does not link the two accounts. So - what do you mean by "...if you verify the email (via email verification)..." - do you mean a verification of the same email with Apple ?  Or do you mean verification of the email by Firebase ?   Again, the later I did but still does not work.